# Expresso Store: pass value from one page to another one

Tags: expresso-store

Just to be clear about my configuration:

I have 2 templates:

1) Start (user makes selection)
2) Destination (I need to display the user's choice)

Start (user makes selection)
Template: {site_url}my_test_channel/Start

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_test_channel"} 
    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"  input:my_input_name1="My_input_name1"  input:my_input_name2="My_input_name2"}

                  <select id="my_input_name1" name="my_input_name1">
                        <option value="option1" selected="selected"> option1 </option>
                        <option value="option2"> option2 </option>
                  </select>


                  <select id="my_input_name2" name="my_input_name2">
                        <option value="option1" selected="selected"> option1 </option>
                        <option value="option2"> option2 </option>
                  </select>


        <a href="{site_url}my_test_channel/Destination">SEND-INFO-TO-DESTINATION</a>

    {/exp:store:product}    
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then in the Destination template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_test_channel"} 
    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"  input:my_input_name1="My_input_name1"  input:my_input_name2="My_input_name2"}

    User chioice1:  {product_details:my_input_name1}

    User chioice2:  {product_details:my_input_name2}


    {/exp:store:product}    
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Nothing happens.

How can I save the values selected on the first page, ad then display them on the second page?

Comment: Can you provide a less contrived example? Why do you need to redisplay user input in the product tag? The product tag only exists to add items to the customer's cart.

Comment: Once the user has added the item to the cart you can use either the `{exp:store:cart}` or `{exp:store:checkout}` tags to display a users selection.

Answer (score 1):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="your-channel"}
    {exp:store:checkout entry_id="{entry_id}"}
        {items}
            {modifiers}
                {modifier_name}: {modifier_value}
            {/modifiers}
        {/items}
    {/exp:store:checkout}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This will give you the results you are looking for on the subsequent page.

Comment: You would probably want to use the `{exp:store:cart}` tag pair as it does not have the extra overhead of creating an html `<form>` element